# WordPress WooCommerce Problem Description

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wpallimport

I use WP All Import and WooCommerce to upload and insert data entries in my WordPress.

The owner of CSV file has a field with name "description", but he has HTML tags.

For instance:

```
<em><strong>hello world</strong></em><strong></strong>
```

These tags are shown on my WordPress.

How can I run these tags (I want to have the owner's formats)?

Comment: Are you saying that when you import the CSV you are seeing `<em><strong>hello world<strong></em>` in your content instead of just `hello world` in bold/italic?

Comment: Yes exactly.. so when i go to preview i see the text with html tags not the final format. i want to appear the format with the text not  <.p> text text text<./p> etc

Comment: try opening your CSV file in a text editor using the correct encoding, and then re-save it using UTF-8. and import again

Comment: it is utf8 its everything ok with encoding the problem is wp all import? not show html tags i dont know

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Do not add comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Comment: What field are you importing the content to? If it is not the standard WP content field it is possible that the field is not html encoding the field value on output in your template...

Answer (score 0):

for explain: This field is woocommerce standard description field if i paste this content manually everything seens ok! if i import content with wp-all import have problem

"with all import"
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLL7L.png)

with out all import everything seens good